# Field creation AP efficiency

Tags: ingress

Should I create two fields with one link or should I create one field at a time? It seems like I get 2.8k AP from 2 fields with one link, and 1.5k from just one field per link. So it would seem like creating them one at a time would be the most efficient method, but I see people telling me to create links that would establish two fields at a time. Any benefits to either of these?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on what you're trying to achieve. If you're trying to gain as much AP as possible, creating one field at a time (two fields with two separate links) is best. Here's the math:

```
313 AP per link established
1250 AP per field created
---
2 fields with 2 separate links > 2 fields with one link
313*2 + 1250*2 > 313*1 + 1250*2
3126 > 2813
```

However, there are a few reasons for why you might want to create two fields with one link.

- If you're short on time, this can be the fastest way to gain a relatively large amount of AP.
- If you're running short on keys or know you want to establish other links with your existing keys, one link creating two fields gets you almost the same amount of AP (313 less).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just add, that sometimes there's no other way to do. I mean, with 1 link, create 2 fields, for example dividing a posible inner triangle.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. It profits from a primitive fact that `626 + 2500` is more than `313 + 2500`, but the reasoning behind it is off the wall. If you are alone in a situation with 4 portals, no links and 5 keys it DOESN'T MATTER AT ALL if you first create the border links and then one through the middle createing 2 fields at a time, or if you create field after field. The CORRECT math is: `313+313+313+313+(313+2x1250) = 4065` and `313+313+(313+1250)+313+(313+1250) = 4065`.

Comment: So if you are ever in a situation where you can create TWO fields with ONE link, there is NO POSSIBILITY WHATSOEVER to create two links, thereby the comparament (`626 > 313`) is not real in such situation. There is NO such situation which the answerer describes. Either you HAVE to create two links to create fields, or you HAVE to create one link to create fields. It's not up to you, it's the current situation. There is a special case of linking though. It is called `onion fields`. Search more about it.

Answer (score 8):

The one case where creating two fields at a time is beneficial is layering. You can create fields on top of existing fields by linking from an "outside" portal to an "inside" portal. Here's a video that shows how:

This will give you more total AP than you could have obtained by creating fields one-at-a-time.

Comment: Just for the record, it is called `Onion Fields`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the situation at hand, on the time you have at the moment, on the topology of the area, etc. There can't be an all around answer to this question.

Suppose you're on a neutralized farming area and you want to improve your fielding stats or just gain the most possible AP. You should build as much fields as possible, meaning that you  would certainly at some point build two adjacent fields with one link. Or if you wanted to improve your linking stats, too, then you would develop a completely different strategy.

The loss of just 313 AP is not such a big thing.